# Javascript URL detection via extension

Tags: javascript, url, dom-events

I'm building a Firefox extension to log user data for a study at university but limited to two websites (Wikipedia and Youtube).

[Another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596749/url-detection-with-javascript) here on Stack Overflow already touched this topic where the following code was used to check for a regex in the URL:

```
if(/^http:\/\/cgi.site.com\/hp\//.test(window.location)) {}
```

So does it suffice to just add an `eventlistener` for the `onload` event in the extension which executes code similar to the above mentioned or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, you are missing that the location is already known before the load event - you don't need that :-) Did you get any errors with that code? If no, then don't ask...

Comment: well since the code I'm writing is contained in the .xul file of the extension, I need a listener to only fire the check when another website is called, in my approach the load event.
Without the listener the code would just be executed once on extension start, which misses the point completely.

Comment: Oh, sure; then you are right. Isn't there also a `navigation` event next to the `load` event?

Comment: couldn't find the mentioned event, but guess there's not that much of an impact for my work. Thanks anyways Bergi